# SP Backup but without any items in the library or list

Tags: backup, restore

Is it possible to perform a backup (either SharePoint backup or sql backup) without any items that are in man-made lists and libraries?

I saw a feature in Metalogix tools where you can copy a site collection without items (howerver lists and libraries will be copied so site structure in good shape).

Can someone please suggest a powershell or codeplex tool or their own custom tool that they created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [SharePoint Content Deployment Wizard](http://spdeploymentwizard.codeplex.com/), it has some options to exclude content.

Or possibly you could copy the site collection *with* contents, and then clean it up?

If none of those work you'll have to look into a third party or some custom development.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the purpose is, but you could always create a template of lists, libraries, and sites that includes all of the settings and things, but no content. This should serve your purpose without any 3rd party tools.

Comment: Good Idea. I may have to repeat this for 70 times in dev since there are 70 site collections. Thanks Lori.

Comment: Save as Template for publishing site is disabled in SPD and not supported by Microsoft.

Comment: I guess I can manually type /_layouts/savetmpl.aspx at the end of the site I am trying to save template as.